# Passing a lot of variables to subroutine v/s Declaring variables within subroutine

Tags: function, parameter-passing, fortran90, function-declaration

I am trying to integrate two Fortran-90 subroutines in one main function. The algorithm used in both the subroutines is logically similar but differs in array sizes (e.g. using 4 parameters to calculate a value instead of 3 etc).

I can either declare the array, allocate memory in main function and pass it as argument to subroutine or have the subroutine do it when called. In former case I will end up passing on a lot of arguments and in the latter case I will end up allocating and de-allocating variables a lot of times but passing only few arguments during subroutine call.

As the code might end up calling the subroutines several thousand times, I want to make sure that I choose the mot efficient way to achieve my goal. Can somebody shed any light on this?

Comment: You can them explcitily or use the common block (public). Passing them allows one to call it in parallel. For constant parameters I usually make them public (common). You probably want to do both and see what the time difference is.

Comment: @Holmz, thanks for the reply. I will try the exercise you suggested and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

If the arguments are conceptually linked you could create an object (derived data type) containing the parameters you want to use as arguments and pass the object to the subroutine.